# Как обновить pip в пайчарм?

Tags: python

Не могу обновить пип какой командой и как это делается?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы можете это сделать, используя консоль:

`python -m pip install –upgrade pip`

2. Также в [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) PyCharm рассказывается как обновлять пакеты.

"File" -> "Settings" -> "Project: " -> "Project Interpreter"， найдите `pip` в списке и обновите, нажав на кнопку "Upgrade Package".